# SQL query for interval of time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables - `user` and `orders`. In user is all information about users in `orders` is orders with `dt_star` and `dt_end` - for services. When they buy a service i write current date in `dt_start` and after 3 months the service is expired. I must send email 5 days before the service is expired on everyone user. I will do this with Cronjob, but the problem is to select 5 days before expired service for everyone user. My query is something like this:

```
`SELECT `user`.* FROM `user` 
LEFT JOIN `orders` ON orders.user_id=user.id 
WHERE CURDATE() > '`orders`.`dt_end`' - interval 5 day 
LIMIT 30`
```

but like this is not working ...

Comment: You need to use the [`DATE_SUB` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to

```
SELECT `user`.* FROM `user` 
  LEFT JOIN `orders` ON orders.user_id=user.id 
   WHERE CURDATE() > DATE_SUB( `orders`.`dt_end` ,interval 5 day )
LIMIT 30
```

Comment: yes, but after 5 min because now do not active "You can accept the answer after 5 min"

Answer (score 2):

In OracleDB it will be kinda like this:

```
SELECT * FROM user, orders
WHERE orders.user_id = user.id
AND sysdate BETWEEN orders.dt_end - 5 AND orders.dt_end;
```

Answer (score 1):

using left join is not correct here. also typecast the output as date

```
`SELECT `user`.* FROM `user`, `orders` 
   where orders.user_id=user.id 
    and CURDATE() = date('`orders`.`dt_end`' - interval 5 day) 
LIMIT 30`
```

this will give list of all users should be notified 5 days before